# Including a header with template into a source file causing an error

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class which includes the template method create inside the header:

**Network.h**

```
class Network
{
    Network(cudnnHandle_t handle, std::vector<int> batch);
    template <typename T, typename... Args, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Block, T>::value>::type* = nullptr> T create(Args&&... args) 
    {
        Block block(handle_, batch_, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        blocks_.push_back(block);
        return block;
    }
};
```

I have another class DACN that Inherits from the Network class and uses the template method inside it's constructor:

**DACN.h**

```
class DACN : public Network
{
public:
    DACN(cudnnHandle_t handle, std::vector<int> batch, int temporal_stride, int action_dim) : Network(handle,batch)
    {
        auto s  = create<Block>(temporal_stride,84,84);
    }
};
```

At this point everything compiles fine without errors. However as soon as i construct the DACN.cpp file and include the DACN.h file:

**DACN.cpp**

```
#include "DACN.h"
```

I get the following error when compiling the DACN.cpp file:

> DACN.h(13): error: no instance of overloaded function "DACN::create"
>   matches the argument list argument types are: (int, int, int)

Why do i get this error?

Comment: What is the signature of your `Block` constructor?

Comment: The Block constructor signature is:

Block(cudnnHandle_t handle, std::vector<int> n, int c, int h, int w, float val = 0.0); 

However why would the Block constructor signature matter? Everything compiles if i do not include DACN.h into the DACN.cpp file.

Comment: @Fiorentino What compiler are you using? How do your files look like? What are other error messages you have?

Comment: @Fiorentino try using `template <typename T, typename... Args> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Block, T>::value, T>::type create(Args&&... args)` instead, to see if it's a compiler issue

Comment: @Fiorentino and do you have `create` function in `DACN` class as well

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I am compiling with NVCC because i am also compiling cuda code. Apparently NVCC has problems dealing with complex template patterns. I now rearranged things such that NVCC calls the GCC compiler on the template substantiation part of the code.

Sorry for taking up your time.